# Creating a function in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my older Symfony 1.4 project, I can create a function in a class for example

```
class Grps extends BaseGrps
{
public function getAllgroupmember()
{
    $voters = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Grps')->createQuery('g')
        ->select('v.firstname')
        ->from('Voters v')
        ->leftJoin('v.Grps g')
        ->where('g.id=?',$this->id);
    return $voters->execute();
}
```

}

and just easily call that function inside template like

```
 <?php foreach($groups as $group): ?>
        <?php if(count($group->getAllgroupmember()) > 0): ?>
        <?php if($group->name != 'NONE'): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $group->id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $group->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php var_dump(count($group->getAllgroupmember())) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

But I m still confused in doing that in Symfony 2(2.7)

I tried to create a function inside repository, since some people told me it's not a good idea to create doctrine queries inside entity.What I tried is this

```
//GrpsRepository.php

class GrpsRepository extends EntityRepository
 {
 public function getAllMemberGroups()
 {
    return $this
         ->createQueryBuilder('g')
         ->select('v.firstname')
         ->from('Voters v')
         ->join('v.Grps g')
         ->where('g.id=?',$this->id )
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult()
    ;
 }
}
```

and call it in twig,

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
        <td>{{ group.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ group.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ group.getAllMemberGroups()| length}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

but It throws error

> Method "getAllMemberGroups" for object "Project\Bundle\DuterteBundle\Entity\Grps" does not exist in DuterteBundle:Voters:groups.html.twig at line 17

What is the correct way in creating function and call it in twig?

Can I create that function from the controller?

```
public function groupsAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $groups = $em->getRepository('DuterteBundle:Grps')->getAllVotersGroups();

    return $this->render('DuterteBundle:Voters:groups.html.twig', array(
        'groups' => $groups,
    ));
}//I used this to render and loop the groups name in twig which successfully render names.
```

Comment: Can you post the properties of your `Grps` entity ?

Comment: @Touki, there are  two ,id and name.Grps entity is related to a Voters entity in a one-to- many relationships.

Comment: Have you declared your repository in your entity file (annotation in php or yml/xml file). You need to check first you've declared it before writting any functions in it.

Comment: Then try to do `{{ group.voters | length }}`

Comment: @Touki, whew..So easy....your suggestion is working..

Comment: @Touki, what if I have a multiple join query? Example voters is related to city and city is related to province.Now i want to query how many voters in a particular province, so I think we should use join.Where to put the function(getAllVotersPerProvince).?In twig template my function will look look this {{ entity.getAllVotersPerProvince() }}